# How to eliminate if-then-else in CLIPS to better optimise code

Tags: backtracking, clips

I am new to CLIPS and the backtracking paradigm does make my head pain.

I am given a question where I need to produce the follow output.

```
Q: Is the patient's temperature more than 39? [yes/no]: yes
    The patient has fever
Q: Does the patient sick over a month? [yes/no]: yes
    We suspect the patient has bacterial infection
Q: How about sore throat? [yes/no]: yes
    We believe the patient has strep throat
```

So as required I defined a few rules to get it working.

```
(defrule rule_1
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT)
  (WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION) =>
  (assert(WE-BELIEVE-THE-PATIENT-HAS-STREP-THROAT))
  (printout t "We believe the patient has strep throat" crlf))

(defrule rule_2
  (THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C) =>
  (assert(THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER)))

(defrule rule_3
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH)
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER) => 
  (assert(WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION)))

(defrule ask-sick
  (start-question) =>
  (printout t "Q: Is the patient's temperature more than 39? [yes/no]: ")
  (bind ?input (readline))
  (if (neq ?input "no")
    then
      (assert (THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C))
      (printout t "The patient has fever" crlf)
      (printout t "Q: Does the patient sick over a month? [yes/no]: ")
      (bind ?input2 (readline))
      (if (neq ?input2 "no")
        then
          (assert (THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH))
          (printout t "We suspect the patient has bacterial infection" crlf)
          (printout t "Q: How about sore throat? [yes/no]: ")
          (bind ?input3 (readline))
          (if (neq ?input3 "no")
            then
              (assert (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT))
          )
      )
  )
)

(deffacts start
  (start-question)
)
```

Eventually I did make the program come to live.

The problem is, at the rule ask-sick, I had to incorporate a bunch of **if-then-else** to get the program working where it does not very much comply with the backtracking paradigm.

Can somebody tell me how should I optimise it as in it knows where to proceed, rule1 -> rule2 / rule3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
(deffunction ask-question (?question $?allowed-values)
   (printout t "Q: " ?question " [" (implode$ ?allowed-values) "] " )
   (bind ?answer (read))
   (if (lexemep ?answer) 
       then (bind ?answer (lowcase ?answer)))
   (while (not (member ?answer ?allowed-values)) do
      (printout t "Q: " ?question " [" (implode$ ?allowed-values) "] ")
      (bind ?answer (read))
      (if (lexemep ?answer) 
          then (bind ?answer (lowcase ?answer))))
   ?answer)

(deffunction yes-or-no (?question)
   (ask-question ?question yes no))

(defrule ask-temperature
  =>
  (bind ?input (yes-or-no "Is the patient's temperature more than 39?"))
  (assert (THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C ?input)))

(defrule ask-sick-for-over-a-month
   (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER yes)
   =>  
   (bind ?input (yes-or-no "Does the patient sick over a month?"))
   (assert (THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH ?input)))

(defrule ask-sore-throat
   (WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION yes)
   =>
   (bind ?input (yes-or-no "How about sore throat?"))
   (assert (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT ?input)))

(defrule conclude-fever
  (THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C yes) 
  =>
  (assert (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER yes))
  (printout t "The patient has fever" crlf))

(defrule conclude-bacterial-infection
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH yes)
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER yes) 
  => 
  (assert (WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION yes))
  (printout t "We suspect the patient has bacterial infection" crlf))

(defrule conclude-strep-throat
  (THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT yes)
  (WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION yes) 
  =>
  (assert (WE-BELIEVE-THE-PATIENT-HAS-STREP-THROAT yes))
  (printout t "We believe the patient has strep throat" crlf))
```

And another:

```
(deffunction ask-question (?question $?allowed-values)
   (printout t "Q: " ?question " [" (implode$ ?allowed-values) "] " )
   (bind ?answer (read))
   (if (lexemep ?answer) 
       then (bind ?answer (lowcase ?answer)))
   (while (not (member ?answer ?allowed-values)) do
      (printout t "Q: " ?question " [" (implode$ ?allowed-values) "] ")
      (bind ?answer (read))
      (if (lexemep ?answer) 
          then (bind ?answer (lowcase ?answer))))
   ?answer)

(deffunction yes-or-no (?question)
   (ask-question ?question yes no))

(deftemplate attribute
   (slot name)
   (slot value))

(deftemplate question
   (slot text)
   (slot attribute)
   (multislot precursors))

(deftemplate conclusion
   (slot text)
   (slot attribute)
   (multislot precursors))

(deffacts questions
   (question
      (text "Is the patient's temperature more than 39?")
      (attribute THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C))
   (question
      (text "Does the patient sick over a month?")
      (attribute THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH)
      (precursors THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER))
   (question
      (text "How about sore throat?")
      (attribute THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT)
      (precursors WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION)))

(deffacts conclusions
   (conclusion
      (text "The patient has fever")
      (attribute THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER)
      (precursors THE-PATIENT-TEMPERATURE-IS-40C))
   (conclusion
      (text "We suspect the patient has bacterial infection")
      (attribute WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION)
      (precursors THE-PATIENT-HAS-BEEN-SICK-OVER-A-MONTH THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-FEVER))
   (conclusion
      (text "We believe the patient has strep throat")
      (attribute WE-BELIEVE-THE-PATIENT-HAS-STREP-THROAT)
      (precursors THE-PATIENT-HAS-A-SORE-THROAT WE-SUSPECT-A-BACTERIAL-INFECTION)))

(defrule ask-question   
    (question (text ?text)
              (attribute ?attr))
    (forall (question (attribute ?attr)
                      (precursors $? ?pre $?))
            (attribute (name ?pre)
                       (value yes)))
    =>
    (bind ?input (yes-or-no ?text))
    (assert (attribute (name ?attr) (value ?input))))

(defrule conclude
    (conclusion (text ?text)
                (attribute ?attr))
    (forall (conclusion (attribute ?attr)
                        (precursors $? ?pre $?))
            (attribute (name ?pre)
                       (value yes)))
    =>
    (assert (attribute (name ?attr) (value yes)))
    (printout t ?text crlf))
```

Comment: Wow! That's really ingenious! Thanks!